# Do we have any Teradata in-built function to identify untranslatable character

Tags: teradata, special-characters, regexp-replace

I'm facing the below issue for a special character value in `Teradata`.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('=H�4l3B7' ,'[^0-9a-zA-Z]' ,' ');
```

Error:

> Failed [6706 : HY000] The string contains an untranslatable character

Teradata version : 16.20

My table is defined as `SET LATIN`.

I need a Teradata builtin function to replace the above special characters.

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('=H�4l3B7' ,'[^0-9a-zA-Z]' ,' ');
select regexp_replace('=H�4l3B7', '[^0-9a-z]', '', 1, 0, 'i')
```

Comment: There's only one error character, `0x1A` in Latin: `oTranslate(col, chr(26), translate(' ' using unicode_to_latin))` You need the TRANSLATE to avoid automatic translation by the optimizer from your Latin column to Unicode.

Comment: Thanks for you reply..
I'm still facing the same issue 
select oTranslate('=H�4l3B7',chr(26), translate(' ' using unicode_to_latin));

Comment: Any literal is Unicode, try it against your column. `'=H�4l3B7'` -> Unicode -> automatically translated -> error. `select oTranslate('=H'||chr(26)||'4l3B7',chr(26), translate(' ' using unicode_to_latin))` works.